# Not getting entity data in broker query

Tags: dxa, brokerquery

For dynamic banners, I have created a new Banner multimedia Schema, `CustomTeaser.class`, `CustomContentList.class` with all required parameters. I have also created `CustomListController` by extending `listController`.

Now in the Broker query results, I am getting the list of banner Ids (id=743) but I am not getting data in the entity.

> DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /system/mvc/Contentlist/Contentlist/List/746-764
>   DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.ListController.handleGetList(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception]
>   DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'contentlistListController'
>   DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/system/mvc/Contentlist/Contentlist/List/746-764] is: -1
>   DEBUG c.s.d.m.c.model.CustomContentList - SimpleBrokerQuery: SimpleBrokerQuery(publicationId=27, schemaId=479, path=null, sort=none, keywordFilters={})
>   DEBUG c.s.d.t.m.impl.DefaultModelBuilder - Expected class is pre-set to class com.sdl.dxa.modules.contentlist.model.CustomTeaser for model EntityModelData(id=743, linkUrl=null, content=null, binaryContent=null, externalContent=null)
>   DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'sourceConverterFactory'
>   DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'r2modelBuilder'
>   DEBUG c.s.d.t.m.i.DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider - No data is found for path FieldPath(head=bannerType, tail=null) for semantic field
>   DEBUG c.s.d.t.m.i.DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider - No data is found for path FieldPath(head=title, tail=null) for semantic field
>   DEBUG c.s.d.t.m.i.DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider - No data is found for path FieldPath(head=introduction, tail=null) for semantic field

Comment: Are you using dxa 2? If so, which template set are you using, dd4t or dxa r2?

Comment: @Quirijn right now, we are using DXA CTP 2

Comment: How this setup is that new DXA CTP 2 installation or upgrades from the previous version?

Comment: You mention you created new classes with all required parameters, but we need to guess which you think those are. I think it is beneficial if you **edit** your question and supply some more details and perhaps some code snippets of your customizations.When your entity is not getting results it sounds like the semantic mapping is failing, which could be related to what you did or didn't do. Mind you DXA 2.0 is released as of Feb 13, so you should really consider upgrading to that (although I don't expect that will fix your issue directly).